# A certain subalgebra of $\mathfrak{e}_8$ over a p-adic field

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-algebras, non-archimedean-fields

Can $\mathfrak{e}_8(\mathrm{k})$ have a maximal subalgebra isomorphic to $\mathfrak{sl}_1(\mathrm{D})\oplus\mathfrak{g}_2(\mathrm{K})$, where $\mathrm{k}$ is a finite extension of some $\mathbb{Q}_p$, $\mathrm{D}$ is a division quaternion algebra over $\mathrm{k}$, and $\mathrm{K}$ is a quadratic extension of $\mathrm{k}$?

Comment: I wish I understood these classifications better, but such a subalgebra would "complexify" (i.e., upon passing to a suitable extension of $\mathrm k$) to $A_1 + G_2$, and Theorem 3.1 of Seitz's "Maximal subgroups of exceptional algebraic groups" seems to suggest that there's no such maximal subgroup.  There's a lot that's swept under the rug there (like the difference between maximality over $\mathrm k$ and over an extension), but, if I'm reading correctly, it seems to suggest that the answer is 'no.'

Comment: The complexification is $A_1G_2G_2$ (which can be maximal in $E_8$), not $A_1G_2$.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/456161/a-certain-subalgebra-of-mathfrake-8-over-a-p-adic-field#comment1181401_456161), ah, yes, sorry, I missed the passage to $\mathrm K$.